# How do I contribute a manual testcase to ubuntu?

Tags: quality

I have a piece of software I like and enjoy using. I want to help make sure the new version is well tested by making a testcase to ensure functionality and prevent regressions. How can I contribute a manual testcase for a package?

Comment: Unless your testcase applies to a piece of software specifically developed for Ubuntu, or it applies to integration between software rather than any single package, you probably need to approach the original developers of the package and submit them a patch.

Comment: share with us more details about what kind of functionality it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have almost everything what you need in a very good tutorial found at this address: [**QATeam/ContributingTestcases/Manual - Ubuntu Wiki**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/ContributingTestcases/Manual).

There is also a nice video screencast about how to contribute a manual testcase to Ubuntu posted on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VO7DdlUSt_4. Many thanks to Nicholas Skaggs for this one :)

I will list only the **things you need to know** before to start:

- **Launchpad** holds the source code for all manual testcases in the [manual testcase project](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-manual-tests/). Code contributions are submitted as [merge requests](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/Review#Proposing_a_merge).
- The **QATracker** is the master repository for all our our testing within ubuntu QA. It records results and helps coordinate our testing events. Learn more about it [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/QATracker). Code committed to the manual testcase project will be utilized for testing on the qatracker.
- **Style Guide** - [a quick review](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/ContributingTestcases/ManualStyleGuide) of how the testcases should look and tips to keep in mind while your writing.

And of course, **requirements**:

- `bzr` (run `sudo apt-get install bzr` in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) to install it).
- Launchpad/Ubuntu SSO account

<sup>Sources: [QATeam/ContributingTestcases/Manual](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/ContributingTestcases/Manual) (last edited 2013-02-21 22:18:29 by [nskaggs](https://launchpad.net/~nskaggs)).</sup>